# Converting Tuple of integers and strings to just a string

Tags: python

I want to convert a tuple which contains strings and integers into a string, I have tried using the '.join' method but this only seems to work for a tuple of strings.

Can anyone help me? I am using Python 3.5, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

```
" ".join(map(str,my_list))
```

I guess ...

or `" ".join(str(x) for x in my_list)`

Comment: Both work on my system using Python 2.7 & 3.7. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

This Might Help

```
>>> a = ( "aty",3,"bob",5,6)
>>> tuple(map( str , a ) )
('aty', '3', 'bob', '5', '6')
```

Comment: ``----> 2 tuple(map(str, a))`` ``'TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`` I get this error message.